# Choices in Telltale's Game of Thrones

Tags: game-of-thrones

In the likes of the Walking Dead the choices didn't really have much of an impact on the story, you might end up with a different companion depending on who you save, or some people might be more enclined to be friendly, but it never felt like there was anything major by selecting specific options.

In Game of Thrones do the choices matter more?  It's a intrigate TV series, so I'm wondering whether each action has any major game changing actions?

It seems like some choices don't have any impact at all (i.e. no notification to say "X feels / thinks / Y").  I've restarted a section a couple of times and noticed no difference other than a slight dialog change.

> One other part of this is does Ethan have to die at the end of the first episode?

Edit: Just for note, I've completed Episode 1 and am part way through the second.  Putting this hear as Studoku warned of spoilers for Ep3.

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer to at least answer the spoilered question without potentially spoiling anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Episode 1-3 minor spoilers:

> Your actions do influence other characters' opinions of you and many actions will cause different dialogue in later scenes.In some cases, picking up an item will allow you to use it but you're still not locking yourself out of options by not doing so.

Episode 1 spoilers only:

> To answer your specific question, Ethan dies at the end of Episode 1 regardless of what you do.

Comment: Someone got a problem with this answer?

Comment: Guess it was changedfor me, I editted the question to mention where I was up to progress-wise.   I hadn't checked the answer on the basis that the original was Episodes 1-3.  Not sure why it was downgraded though, that would be somebody else.